# Am getting a blank screen during installation stage of Arch Linux

Tags: install, arch-linux

I used `dd if=archlinux-2010.05-core-x86_64.iso of=/dev/sdb` to create an installation image on a USB stick and I'm getting a blank screen soon after boot-up. The last message I saw is:

```
Waiting for UDev UEvents to be processed...
```

What am I to do?

[**note**] Am using a TravelMate 6592: Core 2 Duo T7500 2.2GHz processor.

Comment: I am facing a similar issue, though I used unetbootin to create my bootable usb stick

Comment: Try getting to a console. Ctrl-Alt-F1. If that works, boot worked, and X is the problem. If not, your system hasn't booted properly. If the former, the next thing is to look at the X log in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` or similar.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: This problem occurs at installation stage.

Comment: Is it trying to boot up into X? If, so try booting into console mode. This is an option for Debian. I don't know if installers of other distributions support it. (Sorry, didn't realise this was an old question. Perhaps it is no longer relevant?)

Comment: @FaheemMitha: It's the very first installer bootup, before I can do anything at all.

Comment: @FaheemMitha: The problem is likely still relevant, since I don't think Arch has a newer install iso.

Answer (score 3):

Apparently, with this model, the parport_pc module causes udev to hang[1]. You might have to blacklist this module to successfully install Arch.

Adding `disablemodules=parport_pc` to your kernel line[2] should allow udev to proceed.

[1] http://www.mail-archive.com/arch-general@archlinux.org/msg11658.html

[2] When the iso boots and you see the grub menu, press <kbd>e</kbd> to edit, then add that string to the end of the kernel line. Press <kbd>Enter</kbd> then <kbd>b</kbd> to boot.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `nomodeset` and a low resolution like `vga=771` to the kernel line in GRUB.

Comment: I get the same, except that at least I don't get a blank screen. That last line remains at `[BUSY]`.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding `video=SVIDEO-1:d` OR `i915.modeset=0`
It might help if you have integrated Intel video.